# How d3 selection.exit().remove() work

Tags: d3.js, svg, exit

After creating rectangles with this code;

```
   svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(datayh)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "box1")
    .attr("x", xleft)
    .attr("height", function(d){return d[1]})
    .attr("y", function(d){return d[0]})
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" +  x(i) + "," + margin.top + ")"; } )
    .style("fill", colvar);
```

I want to remove them with:

```
d3.select("p4")
   .on("click",function(){
   var norect =svg.selectAll("rect.box1")
                        .data([]);
   var exitrect = norect.exit();
   exitrect.remove();
   });
```

The rectangles are removed if I break point right after extract.remove().  But somehow, they come back at the completion of the anonymous function.  The console shows

```
<g></g>
<g>…</g>
```

where `<g>...</g>` contains the original elements (7 of them). Example:

```
<rect class="box1" x="12" height="194.0277614889706" y="243.8520963541667" width="20" transform="translate(34,30)" style="fill: red;"></rect>
```

Clicking p4 again will add  to the DOM.

```
<g></g>
<g></g>
<g>…</g>
```

It is as if d3 just takes a COPY of the rect's in memory, removes them, add  to the DOM but leaves the original rect's alone.  How can I remove the rect's?  Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Answer (score 0):

For removing elements, `remove()` is sufficient.

```
 d3.select("p4")
   .on("click", function(){
      svg.selectAll("rect.box1").remove();
   });
```

Comment: I was chasing down the wrong path.  I have a p3 that creates the rectangles: d3.select("p3").on("click", function(){ draw();});   The problem is p3 and p4 are in the same div.  So when p4 is clicked, the p4 event handler is evoked, but the p3 event handler runs afterwards. p3 recreates the rect's.  Problem solved when p3 and p4 are in separate div's.